# Value of type 'EditProfileVc' has no member 'storageRef' in swift 4

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database, swift4, firebase-storage

[image: Click here for image]

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
            profileImage.image = image
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            var data = NSData()
            data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage.image!, 0.8)! as NSData
            // set upload path
            let filePath = "\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/\("userPhoto")"
            let metaData = StorageMetadata()
            metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
            self.storageRef.child(filePath).putData(data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }else{
                    //store downloadURL
                    let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
                    //store downloadURL at database
                    self.databaseRef.child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).updateChildValues(["userPhoto": downloadURL])
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: try this  Database.database().reference().child(filePath).putData(data, metadata: metaData)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by using

```
Storage.storage().reference()
```

Instead of

```
self.storageRef
```

Comment: I Used instead of that it shows now as 
"Value of type 'DatabaseReference' has no member 'putData'"

Comment: Means? What you are saying. If you declares storageRef in your current controller then self.storageRef should work.

Comment: Yup sure, But I have faced another issue on next line can u post here!
Error  - Value of type 'EditProfileVc' has no member 'databaseRef

Code - self.databaseRef.child("profileImage").child(Auth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).updateChildValues(["profileImage": downloadURL])

Comment: Use this Database.database().reference() instead of self.databaseRef

Comment: it's working fine, I can see the profile images in firebase.
But how can I retrieve the profile images from the firebase